# ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'nltk.util'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have successfully installed **NLTK**. I have also downloaded necessary packages using nltk.download().

When I run:

```
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentAnalyzer
from nltk.sentiment.util import *
```

I get an **ImportError**:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/sentiment/__init__.py in
    from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/sentiment/vader.py in
    from nltk.util import pairwise

ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'nltk.util' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/util.py)
```

Comment: Which version of nltk did you install and how did you install it? ```pairwise``` is definitely included in ```nltk.util``` (see: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/5365508e752babcd7a1842aba502595049dc7125/nltk/util.py#L1199)

Comment: I have installed NLTK version 3.2.5, using: **pip install --user -U nltk**

Comment: The error looks odd to me. Maybe drop ```ntlk``` via pip and re-install. The current version is 3.6.5

Comment: Tried dropping via pip and re-installing it, still getting the same error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error using python 3.9 and nltk 3.6.5. Maybe someone else has an idea.